# Add resources files to GraalVM native image with Micronaut Gradle

Tags: image, resources, native

I'm working with Micronaut Gradle and GraalVM native image, I've created a project that needs some files in resources directory, it works when I execute my jar file, but when I create the native image it doesn't work. When I create my native image I use this command line:

```
native-image --no-server \
         --class-path mngraalvm.jar \
        -H:EnableURLProtocols=http \
        -H:Name=mngraalvm \
        -H:IncludeResources="logback.xml|application.yml|pythonfunctions/*.*" \
        -H:Log=registerResource: \
        -H:+ReportUnsupportedElementsAtRuntime \
        -H:Class=com.msc.mngraalvm.Application
```

But **IncludeResources** doesn't add my resources files, Do I need to do another configuration in my project or change my native image command? Thanks.